# Permanent authorization token Google API Sheets for php

Tags: php, google-sheets, google-api

I'm working on a project where you need to use Google Api for Google Sheets service to make changes by means of php, but my access token obtained through clicking on the authorization link , lives only 2 hours. The problem is to extend the validity of the token for more than 2 hours, please help with this task.The following is an example of my function to get a Google client:

```
$client = new Google_Client();
$client->setApplicationName('My Project 45639');
//$client->setScopes(Google_Service_Sheets::SPREADSHEETS);
$client->setAuthConfig('credentials.json');
$client->setAccessType('offline');
$client->setPrompt('select_account consent');
$client->setScopes('https://www.googleapis.com/auth/spreadsheets');

// Load previously authorized token from a file, if it exists.
// The file token.json stores the user's access and refresh tokens, and is
// created automatically when the authorization flow completes for the first
// time.
$tokenPath = 'token.json';
if (file_exists($tokenPath)) {
    $accessToken = json_decode(file_get_contents($tokenPath), true);
    $client->setAccessToken($accessToken);
}

// If there is no previous token or it's expired.
if ($client->isAccessTokenExpired()) {
    // Refresh the token if possible, else fetch a new one.
    if ($client->getRefreshToken()) {
        $client->fetchAccessTokenWithRefreshToken($client->getRefreshToken());
    } else {
        // Request authorization from the user.
        //$authUrl = $client->createAuthUrl();
        //printf("%s", $authUrl);
        $authCode = trim('4/aQHXC2H_MmBA3ifDlXmJiDHyEk2m2QCoKrP1YDdAbBZSZBPUMmbINxg');

        // Exchange authorization code for an access token.
        $accessToken = $client->fetchAccessTokenWithAuthCode($authCode);
        $client->setAccessToken($accessToken);

        // Check to see if there was an error.
        if (array_key_exists('error', $accessToken)) {
            throw new Exception(join(', ', $accessToken));
        }
    }
    // Save the token to a file.
    if (!file_exists(dirname($tokenPath))) {
        mkdir(dirname($tokenPath), 0700, true);
    }
    file_put_contents($tokenPath, json_encode($client->getAccessToken()));
}
return $client;
```

Comment: Seems you should, together with your saving of token, also save a timestamp in a variable. Prior to request for a token next time you check the timestamp. If it has not passed 2 hours you do not request for new token. If it has passed 2 hours you request for a new token. If better clarity you can also have a variable that says if token is valid or not, based on the time of 2 hours. Then you can use that variable to check if it is time or not to request for a new token.

Comment: and how to request a token without user participation?

Comment: Depends on the complexity of your solution. If you are admin on your machine and running linux or mac you can setup you can setup a crontab schedule you that could run the php script. There might however be some security restriction to do that. If you have enough experience you could create a service which job is to maintain a valid token. However if you want the solution on basic level you could just incorporate the token checks during the attempt of user trying to trigger the API request.

Comment: I would like to change the token, if necessary, when trying to send an API request , without the user's participation

Comment: You would have to split the logics then, e.g one php file that contains API request and one file that contains the user attempt. By doing that you can isolate the token change and connect that towards the API request.

Comment: Can you show how it can be implemented?